# Magento Community Edition version 1.9.0 Signup not working

Tags: magento-1.9

On Home page the signup option is not working,
when all details in signup page are submitted  and the submit button is clicked, i'm being redirected to `customer/createpost` link, But the page appears as blank. As i can see in the console log, i am getting an internal server error. What can i do about that?

Comment: turn on `display_errors` in the index.php or check apache error logs to see what the error is

Comment: If you are getting an internal server error, can you post the details about that, so that we can do some further investigations?

Comment: i'm getting error on post as 500 internal server error

Comment: You need to debug, as mentioned above. Start with enabling your logs.

Comment: as of now signup is working but for that i have to submit all details then same thing happens page goes blank and when i make hard refresh all work fine means i have to resubmit all details so can you tell me what could be issue

Comment: Hi @Overseas634, were you able to solve the problem? Did you discover in your logs what caused this 500 error? If so, please post it as an answer.